# Paragraph Styles with Character Style for Bullets

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, character-styles

I've created a Paragraph Style which uses a Character style for the bullet (Zaph Dingbat Solid Block).

The Character Style changes horizontal scale to 150% and adding a 50% skew. After applying the Paragraph Style the bullet does not have the Character Style applied. But when using the Character Style outside of the Paragraph Style the style changes.

I'm applying the Character Style through the bullets and numbering panel. I'm NOT manually applying it to the bullets.

Comment: If you apply the character style *after* applying the Paragraph style, does it work then?

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting find. I reproduced your issue in inDesign CS6.

It seems that only the "skew" effect is not applied, and this is true for all fonts. Other overrides, such as font color, baseline shift etc. will show up.

I'm not sure how to fix this problem, but if you want to create custom bullets, maybe this post is worth reading: http://indesignsecrets.com/creating-a-custom-bullet-or-character-with-indyfont.php